# How can you restrict access to a website based on the contents of a Matamask wallet?

Tags: ether, metamask

How can you restrict access to a wordpress website based on the contents of a Matamask wallet? Similar to the BAYC bathroom (https://boredapeyachtclub.com/#/login-bathroom), where you can only log in if you own a specific item? I see there are plugins to allow logging in, but how do you verify a purchase?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what asset or event you are trying to check. Assuming you have an ERC20 token you want to use to grant access, the basic principle you may want to follow is:

1. Make website unavailable by default and request user exposes their Metamask account. You can use below command.

   ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
2. Once you have access to the user's account, create an instance of your token contract in Web3 and query the user's balance

   // create instance
   Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);

   // Query user's balance
   Contract.methods.balanceOf(userAddress).call().then( (balance) => {
   // your logic for granting user access according to balance
   }
3. Implement a logic to determine whether to grant/restrict access based on user's balance.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is wrong. A custom chrome extension, which simulates metamask could return any account for `eth_requestAccounts`. The user must sign a custom login message. Then this signature should be sent to the backend, it checks the signer, checks the balance, and only after this the backend returns the access token or cookie for the user.